# NetlifyCMS Editorial Workflow: Failed to persist entry: TypeError: r.has is not a function

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms

I'm using Gatsby.js + Netlify CMS for my personal blog.

Yesterday, I enabled Editorial Workflow on my blog by following [this link](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/configuration-options/#publish-mode), once it's done, whenever I clicked the Save button on "Writing in Blog Collection" page, it throws an error:

> Failed to persist entry: TypeError: r.has is not a function

Here is the screenshot

[image: error at save]

Also, the Big Green Publish button disappeared as well.

**To reproduce**

1. Go to the Publish Mode on [this page](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/configuration-options/#publish-mode)
2. Add the publish_mode: editorial_workflow into your /admin/config.yml
3. Deploy to the live website
4. Go to the admin page of your website
   [image]
5. Click the New Blog button
6. type anything in the new article
7. click Save button
8. you will see the error message

Here is my Github Repository for my blog:
https://github.com/franva/askwinston

**Applicable Versions:**

- Netlify CMS version: 2.9.6 # "netlify-cms-app": "^2.9.6",
- netlify-cms-core 2.22.1
- netlify-cms-app 2.11.31
- Git provider: GitHub
- OS: Windows 10
- Browser version Firefox 76.0.1 (64-bit)
- Node.JS version: v12.14.1

**CMS configuration**

```
backend:
  name: git-gateway
  branch: master
  repo: franva/askwinston

  commit_messages:
    create: 'Create {{collection}} “{{slug}}”'
    update: 'Update {{collection}} “{{slug}}”'
    delete: 'Delete {{collection}} “{{slug}}”'
    uploadMedia: '[skip ci] Upload “{{path}}”'
    deleteMedia: '[skip ci] Delete “{{path}}”'

media_folder: static/img
public_folder: /img
publish_mode: editorial_workflow
local_backend: true

collections:
  - name: "blog"
    label: "Blog"
    folder: "src/pages/blog"
    create: true
    slug: "{{year}}-{{month}}-{{day}}-{{slug}}"
    fields:
      - {label: "Template Key", name: "templateKey", widget: "hidden", default: "blog-post"}
      - {label: "Title", name: "title", widget: "string"}
      - {label: "Publish Date", name: "date", widget: "datetime"}
      - {label: "Description", name: "description", widget: "text"}
      - {label: "Featured Post", name: "featuredpost", widget: "boolean"}
      - {label: "Featured Image", name: "featuredimage", widget: image}
      - {label: "Body", name: "body", widget: "markdown"}
      - {label: "Tags", name: "tags", widget: "list"}

  - name: "pages"
    label: "Pages"
    files:
      - file: "src/pages/index.md"
        label: "Landing Page"
        name: "index"
        fields:
          - {label: "Template Key", name: "templateKey", widget: "hidden", default: "index-page"}
          - {label: Title, name: title, widget: string}
          - {label: Image, name: image, widget: image}
          - {label: Subheading, name: subheading, widget: string}
          - {label: Mainpitch, name: mainpitch, widget: object, fields: [{label: Description, name: description, widget: text}]}
          - {label: Intro, name: intro, widget: object, fields: [{label: Heading, name: heading, widget: string}, {label: Description, name: description, widget: text}, {label: Blurbs, name: blurbs, widget: list, fields: [{label: Image, name: image, widget: image}, {label: Text, name: text, widget: text}]}]}
          - {label: Main, name: main, widget: object, fields: [{label: Heading, name: heading, widget: string}, {label: Description, name: description, widget: text}, {label: Image1, name: image1, widget: object, fields: [{label: Image, name: image, widget: image}, {label: Alt, name: alt, widget: string}]}, {label: Image2, name: image2, widget: object, fields: [{label: Image, name: image, widget: image}, {label: Alt, name: alt, widget: string}]}, {label: Image3, name: image3, widget: object, fields: [{label: Image, name: image, widget: image}, {label: Alt, name: alt, widget: string}]}]}
      - file: "src/pages/about/index.md"
        label: "About"
        name: "about"
        fields:
          - {label: "Template Key", name: "templateKey", widget: "hidden", default: "about-page"}
          - {label: "Title", name: "title", widget: "string"}
          - {label: "Body", name: "body", widget: "markdown"}
```

Comment: It seems more related to Netlify lambdas rather than with `editorial_workflow` as shown in some GitHub threads such as https://github.com/netlify/netlify-lambda/issues/64

Comment: thanks @FerranBuireu after I deleted my other branches and I have no PRs on Github, it started working. I have no idea what happened....